# Divs hiding and showing in a sequential order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a checkout page and I am structuring it so it is three steps.

1. Shipping info
2. Payment
3. Order confirmation

I am wanting to create this so they sequentially display with only one displaying one at a time. What I have created so far is using the toggle method approach and it somewhat does what I want with making the divs show and hide, but I am wanting this in a more sequential manner, meaning they can't get to step two without completing step 1.

The toggle approach is also an issue in the regards that if I hit button 2, I have hit that button again for it to go away.

Also with toggle approach I created, the shippinginfocontainer (Shipping Info), it never goes away. It always displays. I tried adding display: none to the CSS portion of it, but then it never displays.

The toggle approach is working and is not broken. I am looking for other solutions to possibly add to this to gain the desired effect of making this sequential and not having to "untoggle" a div.

Also I am unable to get the 1st div container (shipping info) to disappear when going to a different div.

```
$( '#button1' ).click(function() {
  $( '.shippinginfocontainer. ).toggle( "slow" );
});
$( '#button2' ).click(function() {
  $('.paymentinfocontainer' ).toggle( "slow" );
});
$( '#button3' ).click(function() {
  $( '.confirmationinfocontainer' ).toggle( "slow" );
});
```

The jsfiddle still doesn't display how I created it. It is only my second time using it...sorry. I just thought it would be an easier way to read the code.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfar54/xps8a2z4/)

Edited...

Comment: Put the code here in the question, not just in the fiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle you didn't load the jQuery library, and you shouldn't put `<script>` tags in the Javascript panel -- jsfiddle puts that code inside a script tag automatically.

Comment: Edited to relay more of what I am looking for

Comment: @Paul [Here is an updated fiddle with fixed problems](https://jsfiddle.net/xps8a2z4/5/). Note you will want to hide the other divs when one is showed. From what it looks like you want to do, you may not want to use `toggle()`.

Comment: See this fiddle with other fixes: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/xps8a2z4/6/

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks for fixing that. I see what I was doing wrong with that now. I didn't know to load the jquery library was on the side there. What would you recommend being a better or best solution?

Comment: @Barmar That is much more of what I was looking for! When the page loads, it still displays all three until a button is selected. How could I make it where the first div (shipping info) shows first by itself?

Comment: @Paul It looks like you are more wanting buttons inside the form to lead to the next part of the form. So I would have the buttons in the form itself, have each show the next form and hide the last (or others).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Yes that is what I am wanting to do. I just went in and added the buttons to inside of the forms. The only thing is that all of the forms show upon page load. Is there a way I can hide form 2 and 3 upon page load and then the JS shows/hides when the appropriate button is clicked?

Comment: @Paul You can do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/xps8a2z4/7/). You can just call `hide()` directly on your elements on load. Have each button show only a certain element (and hide the rest).

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Great! Thanks, that is definitely what I am looking to do! I appreciate your help! Is there anyway to add validation to this system though? I'm completely new to js.

Comment: @Paul Yes you can either do the validation yourself or use a library. What I tend to do is check for input on `keyup` and check if it's valid. For example have the button disabled by default, check that the fullname field is not empty on `keyup`, enable it if it's not empty. [Here is an example of that](https://jsfiddle.net/xps8a2z4/9/)

Comment: On a side note, your HTML is all kinds of broken. I would suggest putting it through a validator. Hints: the only valid child of `ul` is `li`, and as a rule don't put block level elements (`p`) inside phrasing or in-line elements (`span`)

Answer (score 1):

**Here is my code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide1").click(function(){
        $("#p1").show();
        $("#p2").hide();
        $("#p3").hide();
    });
    $("#hide2").click(function(){
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").show();
        $("#p3").hide();
    });
   $("#hide3").click(function(){
        $("#p1").hide();
        $("#p2").hide();
        $("#p3").show();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="p1">Hey there, its me  urs truly p1.</p>
<p id="p2">Hey there, its me  urs truly p2.</p>
<p id="p3">Hey there, its me  urs truly p3.</p>

<button id="hide1">Button1</button>
<button id="hide2">Button2</button>
<button id="hide3">Button3</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have updated your code on jsfiddle kindly check it.

```js
$(function(){
$( '#button1' ).click(function() {
  $( '.shippinginfocontainer' ).toggle( "slow" );
});
$( '#button2' ).click(function() {
  $('.paymentinfocontainer' ).toggle( "slow" );
});


$( '#button3' ).click(function() {
  $( '.confirmationinfocontainer' ).toggle( "slow" );
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="spancenter"><p>Easy three step ordering process</p></span>
    <ul class="checkoutmenu">
     <button class="checkoutbutton" id="button1">1. Shipping Information</button>
     <button class="checkoutbutton" id="button2">2. Payment Information</button>
     <button class="checkoutbutton" id="button3">3. Order Confirmation</button>
    </ul>
<div class="shippinginfocontainer">HELLO DUMMY</div>
<div class="paymentinfocontainer">HELLO DUMMY</div>
<div class="confirmationinfocontainer">HELLO DUMMY</div>
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this code ::

> ```
> $('#button1').click(function(){
>   $(".paymentinfocontainer, .confirmationinfocontainer").hide("slow");
>   $(".shippinginfocontainer").show("slow");
> });
> $('#button2').click(function(){
>   $(".shippinginfocontainer, .confirmationinfocontainer").hide("slow");
>   $(".paymentinfocontainer").show("slow");
> });
> $('#button3').click(function(){
>   $(".paymentinfocontainer, .shippinginfocontainer").hide("slow");
>   $(".confirmationinfocontainer").show("slow");
> });
> ```

[CHECK FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/xps8a2z4/12/)

OR

Try it also : Tested working successfully

```
<button class="checkoutbutton" onclick="showhide('shippinginfocontainer');" id="button1">1. Shipping Information</button>
<button onclick="showhide('paymentinfocontainer');" class="checkoutbutton" id="button2">2. Payment Information</button>
<button onclick="showhide('confirmationinfocontainer');" class="checkoutbutton" id="button3">3. Order Confirmation</button>
```

> ```
> function showhide(show) {
>   var y = ['shippinginfocontainer','paymentinfocontainer','confirmationinfocontainer'];
>   y.splice( $.inArray(show, y), 1 );
>   for(var i=0;i<=y.length;i++) {
>       $("."+y[i]).hide("slow");
>   }
>   $("."+show).show("slow");
> }
> ```